# Make sure value returned from coroutine overwrites default value in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, objectbox

I would like to make sure queried value from database comes always later than default value.

For example

```
class SetTimeFragment : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSetTimeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = FragmentSetTimeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        val dbId = 3
        val defaultTime = LocalTime.now().toString()

        //Set default value
        binding.timeView.setText(defaultTime)


        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {

            val itemList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                //This is Database query
                ObjectBox.store.boxFor(Data::class.java)[dbId]
            }

            // string from database e.g.12:30
            val newTime = itemList.dbTimeStr

            //overwrite default value with database query result
            binding.timeView.setText(newTime)
        }


        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Currently, this code has no problem. But does coroutine possibly return value faster than default value? I mean, database value goes to view first, and default value overwrites it. If it possibly happens, how can I prevent it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coroutine doing the DB query is not even started when the default value is set on the text view, so there is no risk it can finish before that and write a value that would be overwritten by the default

Comment: And even if this were a standard `launch` call with no suspending calls in it such that the coroutine content was run synchronously because of the immediate dispatcher, the default was already synchronously set on the text view before the launch call.